Asus/Intel NUC 12th and 13th Gen: vPro AMT Inaccessible after OS Boot
On the 9th/10th/11th gen NUCs, I don't recall having a problem setting up vPRO/IME/AMT. At POST we press Ctrl+P or similar, we set a password, we set user consent to None, we activate the network settings with DHCP.
Then we can browse to the AMT with http://:16992. We can load Mesh Commander and control the screen, BIOS, power, etc.
With the NUC12 and NUC13 on my setup bench, we've done all the usual setup, except instead of Ctrl+P, they've moved the vPro setup into BIOS under Advanced, MEBx. It has all the usual settings.
We can access the vPro webpage before the OS boots, but once the OS boots, vPro webpage becomes inaccessible. Any ideas?
a) The IP address should be the same IP address as the OS gets. vPro and OS are set to DHCP.
b) vPro should be diverting the port before it gets to Windows, so no firewall should get in the way, but tested with firewall disabled anyway.
Any other ideas?

After beating my head against the desk for longer than I would like to admit, I figured this out, finding your post in the process.
Have a look at this article. https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Faccessingintelamtviathewebuiinterface.htm
Basically, the old method had been depreciated.
Try https://:16993 and in MeshCommander use Auth/Security Digest/TLS
